# Issue with execution on TestNG include tag

Tags: testng

Below is my testng.xml file , when executing , It runs few test cases from one class (class A ) and then starts execution from other class (class B). While skipping few of the classes

```
<suite name="Suite">
<test name="test">
<groups>
  <run>    
    <include name="Server"/>
    <include name="Windows"/>
  </run>
</groups>
    <packages>
      <package name="com.cloud.eps.tests.all.*"></package>
      <package name="com.cloud.eps.tests.v1_0.*"></package>
      <package name="com.cloud.eps.tests.v1_1.*"></package>
   </packages>
 </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

But if i remove include tag. Then it run all test cases from class A and then from Class B

Comment: Which version of TestNG are you using? Please include also samples of  code from class A and class B. Can you see any pattern in which test-cases run and which ones are skipped?

Answer (score 0):

The number of test methods executed depends on How many test methods in Class A or Class B were included in the group "Server" or "Windows"?

Please note that group name in testng.xml looks for the test cases belong to that particular group and executes that particular test cases alone.

Considering the below test methods in your Class A

```
@Test (groups = { "Server"})
public void testMethod1(){
}

@Test (groups = { "Windows"})   
public void testMethod2(){
}

@Test (groups = { "ThirdGroup"})
public void testMethod3(){
}
```

And your testng.xml has

```
<groups>
  <run>    
    <include name="Server"/>
    <include name="Windows"/>
  </run>
</groups>
```

As there are two groups included in testng.xml, "Server" & "Windows", Your testng.xml picks only first two test methods(testMethod1 & testMethod2) **leaving third method(testMethod3)** as it belongs to the different group which doesn't include in testng.xml

On removal of Included tag, it **doesn't restrict the execution to group level** and executes all test methods

Comment: In my case ,The group is  server / windows in both in class A and Class B.